# Avoid Google Site Search indexing certain parts of page

Tags: indexing, search-engine, google-search, google-custom-search

We use Google Site Search for our site search, and we've had a problem with it indexing the related products snippet, which isn't relevant to the product in question..

```
<!--googleoff: all-->
--Related products snippet--
<!--googleon: all-->
```

The issue is, this hasn't been working and now when you search for a title that is in another products related products, you'll get results that are not relevant to the search term.

How do I prevent google from indexing a certain part of the page for use in our internal site search.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control Googlebot directly but you can drop strong hints.

A method for this is using HTML elements - the Google bot will see anything in an  container as being highly relevant to the page's content. Make sure that these match the page title/header.

Parts of the page you don't want indexed or scraped for custom SERP descriptions you can place in  containers. This works well with sidebars, cookie policies and boiler plates.